# Parsing XML file using jquery dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, xml-parsing

I know the below question is very common , but i cant help myself posting here , since am little confused of what am doing in my code ...

I am sending an AJAX request and getting XML as response , 
As of now am parsing it based on the tag name like below :

```
$(xml).find('Details').each(function(){
                        //email=$(this).find('Email').text();
                         $tbl.append($('<tr>').append(

                             $('<td>').text($(this).find('name').text()),
                             $('<td>').text($(this).find('LastName').text()),
                             $('<td>').text($(this).find('City').text()),
                             $('<td>').html("<a href='insert.jsp?email="+$(this).find('Email').text()+"&mode=Search"+" ' >"+$(this).find('Email').text()+"</a>"),
                             $('<td>').html("<a href='MyServlet?email="+$(this).find('Email').text()+"&mode=Delete"+" ' >"+"Delete"+"</a>")
                             ));
                });
```

The functionality what am trying to do is absolutely working fine ,

**Problem :**

How to parse the XML response dynamically without knowing the tag name or the parent ?

i referred the below links for that  : 
[XML Parsing with jQuery]

And i have to use only jquery :
any kind of help is appreciable .. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look through the [Traversing API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

There are quite a few functions where you can parse and move through the XML without actually knowing the tags.  Some key ones for you would be `children()` `next()` `siblings()` and as you already know `each()`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you, do check the [jquery](http://flexigrid.info/) plug-in and also basic [jquery-xml-parser.](http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/01/jquery-xml-parser/)

Comment: thanks for the response , am not looking for how to load in table , what am looking is how to parse XML without knowing the root or child elements